# Using for loop twice to print keys of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary called thisdict.

```
thisdict = {
"a": "1",
"b": "2",
"c": "3",
"d": "4"
}
```

And I have the code below:

```
> for k in thisdict:
>     for p in thisdict:
>             print (p)
```

I don't understand why the result would be

> a b c d a b c d a b c d a b c d

Comment: You do not need the second loop

Comment: The inner loop prints all the keys.  The outer loop repeats that process four times.  Why do you have two loops anyway?

Comment: The two loops are completely independent.  Even though they're iterating over the same `thisdict` they don't affect each other in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
 for k in thisdict:
     print (k)
     for p in thisdict:
             print (p)
```

the result is
**a** a b c d **b** a b c d **c** a b c d **d** a b c d

But you don't display *k* so you have :
a b c d a b c d a b c d a b c d

Answer (score 0):

you iterate through the keys when going through a dictionary, going through the iteration with k you iterate 4 times (a through d) and the p iteration iterates 4 times per each k iteration, meaning you got 16 prints in total. That means you printed the keys of the dictionary 4 times after each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the entire dictionary on the outer loop, where `k` is the value of the key. This will iterate 4 times.

Then for each of these iterations, you are then iterating the entire list again, where `p` is the value of the key. This will also iterate 4 times.

Overall you will be iterating and printing `p` 4x4, or 16, times.

This will result in printing `a b c d` four times in a row.